# Do Carmo DG Q. 1.7.2 finding the arc with a given length which bounds the largest area

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

I'm struggling with the following question for long. I tried to apply isoperimetric inequality $4\pi A\leq L^2$, but my attempt has been unsuccessful. Could anyone give me a hint?

Let $AB$ be a segment of straight line and let $l>$ length of $AB$. Show that the curve $C$ joining $A$ and $B$, with length $l$, and such that together with $AB$ bounds the largest possible area is an arc of a circle passing through $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approximate the curve with a sequence of connected straight line segments. Combine this with the straight line segment AB to form a polygon. Now use the theorem that the polygon with maximum area, given the sides, can be circumscribed by a circle.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! So, in order to obtain the curve with the desired shape, I need to make that circumscribed polygon to the curve with the segment AB and an arc. If I don't need to fix the length of AB, it's easy to proceed, since the curve with the largest area is regular polygon and therefore I get a circle eventually. But in this case, I have to fix AB. Sorry, I can't figure out what to do in the next.

Comment: No. The polygon consists of the given length AB, along with the many small segments approximating the curve. If all these lengths, including AB, are given, the area of the polygon will be maximized when it can be circumscribed by a circle. The segment AB will then be a chord of the circumscribing circle.